# Returning values from text file : C#

Tags: c#, split, text-files, streamreader

I have a .txt file that contains information about vehicles that I add via another project. I want to read the text file, retrieve each VIN number, and place just the actual number itself in a combo box when the form is loaded.
The info for each vehicle in the txt file looks like:

Model: 'model'

Manufacturer: 'manufacturer'

VIN Number: 'VIN number'

This is what I have:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\carCenter\carCenter\bin\Debug\Vehicles.txt"))
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\carCenter\carCenter\bin\Debug\Vehicles.txt");
            foreach(string line in lines)
            {
                if (line.Contains("VIN"))
                {
                    Char colon = ':';
                    string[] vins = line.Split(new string[] {"VIN Number: "}, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                    {
                        foreach(var vin in vins)
                        {
                            vinComboBox.Items.Add(vins[i]);
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: And what is the exact question? What are you struggling with?

Comment: Well it's not adding the vin numbers to the combobox, is there a way to split the label("VIN Number: ") from the actual number? Sorry, I wasn't very clear

Comment: What kind of UI is this code for - WinForms, WPF, or ASP.Net?

Comment: WinForms. I have 2 C# projects inside 1 solution, each with their own form (1 to add the information to the .tt file and the other to display the VIN numbers in a combobox and eventually match the corresponding VIN number to that vehicle's info and display that into textboxes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to have a general purpose function like this:

```
private String GetDataToRightOfLastColon(String line)
{
  line = line.Trim();

  var indexOfLastColon = line.LastIndexOf(':');

  /* If line does not contain a ':' character,
     or ':' is the last non-space character in line,
     throw an exception. */
  if ((indexOfLastColon == -1) || (indexOfLastColon == (line.Length - 1)))
    throw new ArgumentException(
      String.Format("The line '{0}' does not have the correct format.", line));

  return line.Substring(indexOfLastColon + 1).Trim();
}
```

Next, apply that function via LINQ to process the text file and populate the combobox:

```
vinComboBox.Items.AddRange(
  File
  .ReadAllLines(@"D:\carCenter\carCenter\bin\Debug\Vehicles.txt")
  .Where(line => line.Trim().StartsWith("VIN"))
  .Select(line => GetDataToRightOfLastColon(line))
  .ToArray()
);
```

Comment: This seems like it could work! Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with LINQ. Do I add the second block of code inside my Form_Load event or do I put it somewhere else? Thanks

Comment: Replace the entire code block in your original question with the `vinComboBox.Items.AddRange(...);` code.

Comment: Ok I did that and it's giving me the error 'Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'object[]'

Comment: @NoahHornak - If your input files are well-formed I would replace the `GetDataToRightOfLastColon` method call with `.Select(line => line.Split(';').Last().Trim())`.